# Computing limit involving exponential: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2e^{-\frac{2}{x}}-5e^{-\frac{5}{x}}}{e^{-\frac{2}{x}}-e^{-\frac{5}{x}}}+x$

Tags: real-analysis

Evaluate the following limit?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{2e^{-\frac{2}{x}}-5e^{-\frac{5}{x}}}{e^{-\frac{2}{x}}-e^{-\frac{5}{x}}}+x$$

What is a standard way to compute this limit?

Comment: @A---B. Why do you think so ?

Comment: Limit doesn't exist..if we apply lopital rule the limit comes out to be infinite

Comment: Actually the limit does exist.  Are people ignoring the $+x$ on the end?

Comment: @tilper. This is exactly the problem from the start !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I did not see that $x$ in the end. sorry :((.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

with $y=\frac {1}{x} $ and
After simplification it becomes

$$2+\frac {-3}{e^{3y}-1}+\frac {1}{y} $$

$$=2+\frac {-3y+e^{3y}-1}{y(e^{3y}-1)} $$

the numerator is equivalent to $$\frac {9y^2}{2} $$
while the denominator is equivalent to $$3y^2$$

the limit is then $$2+\frac {3}{2} =\frac {7}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Start using $x=\frac 1y$ which makes $$\frac{2e^{-\frac{2}{x}}-5e^{-\frac{5}{x}}}{e^{-\frac{2}{x}}-e^{-\frac{5}{x}}}=\frac {2e^{-2y}-5e^{-5y}}{e^{-2y}-e^{-5y}}$$ and consider Taylor series around $y=0$ first for numerator and denominator.